# Browser ignoring set-cookie header from CORS response (asp.net core 2.0 web api)

Tags: cors, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an Angular 4 application calling a web api built with asp.net core 1.1 on a different server. Both the front end and the back end are configured for enabling CORS. Everything was working fine until the back end was upgraded to asp.net core 2.0. Then the browser stopped respecting the Set-Cookie headers in the repsonses sent from the web api. As the web api uses cookies for session management, the application stopped working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In version 2.0, asp.net core introduced a new behavior: by default it adds a 'samesite=lax' attribute to all set-cookie headers, which effectively disables CORS.
The solution is to explicitly override this default behavior in Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
           services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

---

It took me many hours to find this solution, mainly because the application didn't break immediately after the upgrade to 2.0, so I put most of the effort in searching for the culprit in the front end.
The reason it didn't break immediately was

1. I do most of the developement in Firefox, and with version 57.0 it still doesn't seem to respect the (somewhat new) samesite attribute.
2. even in Chrome the problem didn't show up on my machine because there already existed an old cookie for the site, from before the upgrade, which didn't have the attribute set.

After identifying and solving the problem, I found articles from other developers, from different platforms than asp.net, who also suffered from unexpected problems caused by this newly introduced attribute. I hope what I've written here might save others from going through the same agony.

Comment: What are your other settings with cors and cookies. I have these with cookies 
.AddCookie("localhost", options => 
{
options.Cookie.Domain = "localhost";
options.Cookie.Name = "localhost_access_token";
options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
options.LoginPath = "/login";
options.LogoutPath = "/login";
})
and this with cors
options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOriginsForMusiple",
builder =>
{
builder
.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();});

Comment: Currently I am getting this exception: "The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*'" How can I get .net core to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to something else than*

Comment: @JanneHarju - The only settings I have are the one listed above 
In Startup.ConfigureServices, plus the following in Startup.Configure:

app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
I never had any problem with wildcards. The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response is always a full url.

Comment: Yep I found my problem. My site is on Azure and azure's own cors settings was take Control about cors. I cleared that list and now I get. Net core's cors settings to take Control.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me, but gave me the clue that I needed. For me I added this to my ConfigureServices

services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            });